# Click to Enlarge Image on Tumblr page

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr, image-enlarge

On my Tumblr page, when a user click on my image, I want the image to enlarge.
[Click here](http://stampsmakesart.tumblr.com/) for an example of a Tumblr page that does what I want. The Image enlarges once its being clicked on, and it returns back to the Tumblr page when the user clicks on the area that isn't the image.

I tired searching for a solution for a few days now, but nobody that I know seems to know how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suggest looking at the Tumblr theme documentation on how to add `photoset` support to your theme: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#photoset-posts

Answer (score 3):

I believe she uses the tumblr photoset feature - 
http://support.tumblr.com/post/41532540119/the-new-photosets.

The actual script being used onClick of the image is rapid click http://l.yimg.com/ss/rapid-3.18.1.js

Comment: I've tired the new photoset feature. I uploaded multiple images in one post. Nothing seems to be happening when I click on the images on my Tumblr page. I'm not sure what do to with the script that you've given me.

Comment: You can try using her theme, perhaps it implements the photoset navigation - http://adessive.tumblr.com/